# Can LIMIT alter results of queries?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, limit

I have a database like twitter who have users and msgs and users can subscribe and block other users. I need to show msgs from subscribed users that are not blocked, so i have a query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT M.mid, M.author, M.content FROM Msgs M, Subs S, Blocks B
WHERE S.uid = 3 AND S.sub_uid = M.author AND B.uid = 3 AND M.author NOT IN
    (SELECT B2.bl_uid FROM Blocks B2 WHERE B2.uid = 3)
ORDER BY M.mid DESC LIMIT 30;
```

Without 'LIMIT 30' the query works fine, gives me only the correct rows, but with 'LIMIT 30' i have wrong results, because the query gives me the correct rows plus rows that belong to users that are subscribed AND blocked. How can 'LIMIT' alter that result?

EDIT: The user who has uid = 3 has another 2 users subscribed, users 5 and 6, and user 6 is blocked, so i need to show only msgs from user 5, but with 'LIMIT 30' the msgs from user 6 are also returned.

Comment: Can you supply an SQL Fiddle example (www.sqlfiddle.com)?  Or at minimum, sample data and desired results.

Comment: Run you sub-query by itself.  Does it return at least 1 `NULL`?

Answer (score 0):

Just a total guess here, but I find myself wondering if the limit clause is being applied to the subquery as well, essentially only blocking the first 30 authors in the `Blocks` table.

Try refactoring the query to avoid using a subquery.

As a bonus, you'll eliminate [performance problems inherent in the subquery implementation in MySQL](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/10/25/mysql-limitations-part-3-subqueries/) when you start to add more than just a little data.

Comment: Even if the 'LIMIT' clause is being applied to the subquery too, the restrictions of the 'WHERE' clause should return only the correct results. I have tried to do it without the subquery before, but it doesn't work, besides my teacher said that it should be with the subquery when i showed him the query without that. Does someone know how to do it without the subquery? I don't care about the performance in this specific case, although i know about the adjacent problems.